How to properly pair/bond a BLE device with LE Secure Connections to a windows laptop?
I've made a custom device which uses a Nordic Semiconductors MCU. I have a python GUI which uses the bleak library and has no issue connecting and communicating with the device when it uses open broadcast. However, I run into issues when I implement security (LE Secure Connections) with a static passkey. I intend to bond the device to the PC before communicating with the GUI as bleak does not support pairing.
I have already established that the pairing works completely fine with both the nRF connect mobile app and a custom flutter android app. This is an issue only encountered when pairing with a windows PC.
According to the debug logs it connects, but before any bonding occurs, it disconnects after 10 seconds. The error codes are nondescript. Upon disconnect, the RPA automatically changes and the device starts advertising again. That is expected behavior. The unexpected behavior is the lack of pairing and forced disconnect. On the PC, there is no prompted passkey to enter.

I used a sniffer to capture the packets. This is the entire sequence exchanged before PC and MCU disconnect. I am new to BLE and researching so I do not know the exact correct sequence of exchanges.

Is there anything that stands out with this capture? I can share the wireshark .pcapng if required. Is there a way that windows does BLE bonding which differs from that of mobile devices?

You should under no circumstances use static passkey for LE Secure Connections (see https://insinuator.net/2021/10/change-your-ble-passkey-like-you-change-your-underwear/). In any case, error code 8 on the radio level just means the connection was simply unexpectedly dropped. If this happens at a particular stage every time, I guess your firmware in the peripheral crashes at that point, leading to the disconnecting of the Link Layer. The Windows side should not be the issue.

I understand I shouldn't use a static passkey, but the device has nothing but a button. Upon clicking the button, the device advertises and becomes available for pairing for 1 minute before going to low-power mode again. I could add a static MAC address and the static passkey. What are the alternative secure pairing methods which could work on such a device? I am trying to avoid fancy complicated stuff like OOB with NFC  but I still want the security.
As for the firmware crashing, I don't see how that would be the case. When the MCU reboots, it prints that to the RTT terminal.

Have you read this: https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/104258/security-failed-level-1-err-9-connecting-error-with-bonded-device ?
Regarding static passkey, I agree with Emil, security by obscurity has never worked.

@Risto I want to kiss you. I briefly looked through that post a bit ago, but I did not go 25 messages deep to where the answer was. Disabling the PHY update procedure on the peripheral side does solve the pairing problems. I also made a post on nordic forums which I'm going to leave open longer because I would like to know why that occurs.

@AuFries I agree that it's not so obvious that incompatible ‘paring parameters’ will cause the device pairing to abort, but that's the way secure device pairing works.

I'm self-answering this post to close it. Emil and Risto provided information for the workaround by disabling the PHY update on the peripheral, however it was ultimately a firmware issue with my intel Bluetooth driver which was outdated. See the nordic forum links for more information.
